# Link to SMS app does not open in Android mail

Tags: android, ios, email, sms, deep-linking

I've done searches and troubleshooting, but can't seem to figure this out.

I'm trying to send out emails containing a pre-filled SMS. This works for iOS, and on Android when opened in the browser. However, the email client on Android does not allow these links? Is there any way to fix it?

sms:?body=Hello

I was thinking of using a URL shortener to create a http reference, but these services only allow web links.

Ideally I would have one link that launches SMS on both Android and iOS, and opens email or a web link on other devices.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could host your own 'link shortener' with JS redirects. You'd basically just need to put a page somewhere on your website and include something like this on it:

```
<script>
    window.location = "sms://";
</script>
```

Build out some additional platform-specific redirect logic, and then put the URL of that page in your email.